# Rails 6 - password showing up in logs even though I added it to the "filter_parameters"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am having a simple method for logging users' activity, looks a bit like this:

```
def log_activity
  ...
  log_activity.params = params.inspect
  log_activity.save
  ...
end
```

When I look to the terminal console (and then to the DB), I can see there printed out the password:

> LogActivity Create (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO ... ("user_id", ..., "params")
> VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) RETURNING "id"
> [["user_id", 13], ["params", "#<ActionController::Parameters
> {"authenticity_token"=>"gIHGES_Y74nFAtJ1xoH5YD3e28uPJ-icdDAqkGufjhfjdjhgfjhf",
> "user"=>{"email"=>"my@email.com",
> "password"=>"my-secret-password", "remember_me"=>"0"},
> "commit"=>"Log in", "controller"=>"devise/sessions",
> "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>"], ["msg", "successfully
> signed in."], ["created_at", "2021-04-24 08:50:16.262145"],
> ["updated_at", "2021-04-24 08:50:16.262145"]]

How do I hide it from here and prevent it from saving to the DB? I can probably check the `params` and manually remove it from the hash, however - is there a more elegant way doing it?

I've read that I can disable logging the password by adding it to the `config/filter_parameter_logging.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [
  :passw, :secret, :token, :_key, :crypt, :salt, :certificate, :otp, :ssn, :password
]
```

or adding it to the model (`LogActivity.rb`):

```
class LogActivity < ApplicationRecord
  self.filter_attributes=[:password]
end
```

or adding it to the `application.rb` file:

```
config.filter_parameters += ["password"]
```

However, even after restarting the server, none of these actions worked for me and the password is always shown in the terminal window and then stored in the database.

How do I filter it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `request.filtered_parameters` to get the filtered parameters based on your `Rails.application.config.filter_parameters` configuration:

```
def log_activity
  ...
  log_activity.params = request.filtered_parameters.inspect
  log_activity.save
  ...
end
```